# Symfony2 getdoctrine outside of Model/Controller

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to getDoctrine() outside of the controller.
I've created this service:

config/services.yml

```
services:
  update_command:
    class: project\projBundle\Command\Update
    arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager']
```

and in my app/config/config.yml

```
imports:
    - { resource: "@projectprojBundle/Resources/config/services.yml" }
```

so and the class that I want to use:

```
namespace project\projBundle\Command;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class Update {
    protected $em;
    public function __construct(EntityManager $em) {
        $this->em = $em;
    }
```

but every time I want to do this: (**I'm doing this right?**)

```
$up = new Update();
```

i got this error:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to ...\Update::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager, none given, called in .../Update.php line 7
```

Comment: have you symfony2 version with vendors? this sounds weird to me ...

Comment: yes I just update the vendors

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Simple solution**

If you're implementing a Symfony command (that can be executed in a cron tab), you can access the service container from the command.

```
<?php
namespace MyProject\MyBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class UpdateCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    protected $em;

    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('myproject:mybundle:update') ;
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $this->em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
    }
}
```

That way, you get the entity manager from a command and don't need to declare this class as a service. You can therefore remove the configuration you added in the `services.yml` file.

**An other solution (cleaner)**

This solution allows better separation of concerns and can therefore be easily unit tested and reused in other parts of your Symfony application (not only as a command).

Move all the logic part of your "update" command to a dedicated class that you will declare as a service:

```
<?php
namespace MyProject\MyBundle\Service;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class MyUpdater
{
    protected $em;

    public function __construct($em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function runUpdate()
    {
        // All your logic code here
    }
}
```

Declare it as a service in your `services.yml` file:

```
services:
    myproject.mybundle.myupdater:
        class: MyProject\MyBundle\Service\MyUpdater
        arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager']
```

Simply call your service from your command :

```
<?php
namespace MyProject\MyBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class UpdateCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('myproject:mybundle:update') ;
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $myUpdater = $this->getContainer()->get('myproject.mybundle.myupdater');
        $myUpdater->runUpdate();
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, is exactly this what I want to do. but now im getting a different error: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getKernel() on a non-object in /var/www/project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Command/ContainerAwareCommand.php on line 36. I.m following the cookbook and I dont understand this error

Comment: I edited my code and this error is fixed.
You have to move the initialization to the `execute` method.

Comment: `ContainerAwareCommand` is just a class that itself extends `ContainerAware` ... @BrunoRamalho you didnt mention you're trying to get the entity-manager inside a command but you were talking about general non-controller classes so this answer is only an addition to mine.

Comment: And by the way, an other nice solution would be to move all the logic part of your command (i.e. code that really does the update, whatever it is) to an other class.
This other class would be declared as a service in the `services.yml` file (as you did before), and would take the entity manager as a parameter.
And then, you could call this service from the command. That would be a best practice to do so. I'm going to add an other answer explaining it.

Comment: You can now have a look at my other solution, which is cleaner than the first one as it can easily be unit tested and can be used elsewhere in your Symfony application.

The first one is faster to implement though.

Comment: nice roundup - the cleanest solution would be not injecting the whole container / using ContainerAware at all but only injecting the single service.

Comment: @MichaëlPerrin I understand your solution and I think is the best for my case. I deleted the line in config.yml, then I created the updater class. but now I'm getting another error: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'project\projBundle\Sevice\Updater' not found in /var/www/project/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 1663

Comment: @BrunoRamalho It works fine for me. I guess you made a mistake in one of the namespaces declarations (beware when copying and pasting my code) or class names.

Comment: exactly! its working pretty fine and in my point of view is the best approach. thank you

Answer (score 2):

You have to either inject your newly created `@update_command` service or get it from the container in order to have the `@doctrine.orm.entity_manager` service injected automatically.

You're just creating the object with no argument, not a service. Update expects to retrieve an entity manager instance but you don't provide it.

```
$up = new Update();
```

In a `ContainerAware` class like a controller get your service like this:

```
 $up = $this->container->get('update_command');
```

Otherwise turn the class where you want to use the `update_command` into a service aswell and inject `@update_command` as you did with the entity manager in the service itself.

Comment: yes this is the correct answer. btw now the update could help us, new Update() wasn't here last time I checked this question :P

Comment: Hehe i already wondered about the comments ... this is probably the most-made mistake when people start working with the service container.

Comment: Your controller class can be added to the container as a service aswell - see [**How to define Controllers as Services**](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html).

Comment: but there's some other way just to use the getDoctrine in this class? because i just need this to execute in cron tab

Comment: From a controller that extends `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller` inside an action you could just do something like `$up = new Update($this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager());`. That way you don't need to create the service. What's the remaining problem here? It's the symfony-way to solve this - using defined services and dependency injection is best practice to get the entity manager.

Answer (score 0):

remove below codes in app/config/config.yml, your services.yml will  be autoload...

```
imports:
    - { resource: "@projectprojBundle/Resources/config/services.yml" }
```

in a Action new a instance you can do:

```
  $up = $this->get('update_command');
```

Comment: copy yours? --!I answered earlier than you,when i edit my answer and refresh the page,i saw your answer.