# Symfony2 Outside class

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I use symfony2 (2.6) and I have class to global variable to twig. For Example, class menu:

```
namespace Cms\PageBundle\Twig;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
class Menu {
    protected $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }
    public function show(){
       /******/
    }
}
```

and services.yml

```
services:
    class_menu:
        class: Cms\PageBundle\Twig\Menu
        arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager']

    twig_menu:
        class: Cms\PageBundle\Twig\Menu
```

See:

> ContextErrorException in Menu.php line 9:
>   Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Cms\PageBundle\Twig\Menu::__construct() must be an instance of
>   Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager, none given, called in
>   /home/cms/public_html/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on
>   line 3834 and defined

General, any class (outside) have problem with the constructor and (argument) doctrine.
Why?

[Symfony2 getdoctrine outside of Model/Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19855251/symfony2-getdoctrine-outside-of-model-controller)

Comment: try without '         `arguments: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager]`

Comment: @Matteo: No change. I tried with ", ' and whitout it. I don't understand it.

Comment: try removing the type on the costructor as     `public function __construct( $em)`

Comment: Ok. No changes. Clear cache too.

Comment: Where is: function __construct($em), see: `Warning: Missing argument 1 for Cms\PageBundle\Twig\Menu::__construct(), called in /home/cms/public_html/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 3834 and defined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is totally expected. `Symfony2` expects to create service instance by invoking the `__construct` constructor. If you want to keep the single class in play, you will need to remove that `__construct` and use `setter` dependency injection instead.

There is an official documentation on this: [Optional Dependencies: Setter Injection](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#optional-dependencies-setter-injection)

Basically, you do not pass the `EntityManager` instance during the creation of an service instance but rather "set it later".

Hope this helps.

### Update:

If you fallback to your original solution, make sure you pass `EntityManager` in both instances:

```
services:
    class_menu:
        class: Cms\PageBundle\Twig\Menu
        arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager']

    twig_menu:
        class: Cms\PageBundle\Twig\Menu
        arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager']
```

Comment: Ok. I use setter. services: `calls:  - [setDoctrine, ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]]` and function `setDoctrine(EntityManager $em)` and em returns NULL.

Comment: Yes. In one instance you will set `call` and in another you won't ;)

Comment: `call: [setDoctrine, ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager']]` and nothing :(

Comment: But, wait just a bit. Do you require `EntityManager` in both services? If so, you can fallback to your original solution using the `__construct`, but you *need* to pass your entity manager service.